# Javascript function in a .js cannot getElementById in the .html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a login.js which has a function which is called when the clickme button in the HTML is pressed.

```
document.getElementById('clickMe').addEventListener('click',execuateAllCode);
```

The line below is in the function that is called by the clickme button and it does not work

```
var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
```

It gives this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
```

popup.html contains this code:

```
...
<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickMe"/>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="temppassword" placeholder="Password"/>
...
```

The error should mean that there is no element that contains an id="password". But I do have something with that id. Can the function in login.js not "see" the input in the HTML file?

EDIT 1:
I have tried to add:

```
window.onload = function() {
  execuateAllCode()
};
```

To the .js file, but this does not get rid of the error, it also causes errors in other parts of the code and stops the styling.

The HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
<body>
    <input id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme"/>
    <script language="javascript" src="login.js"></script>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="username" value="user@email.com" placeholder="Email"/>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="temppass" placeholder="Password"/>
</body>
</html>
```

login.js:

```
document.getElementById('clickMe').addEventListener('click',execuateAllCode);
function execuateAllCode() {
    document.write("<br />" + "From login" + "<br />");
    var output;
    output = FunctionOne();
    document.write("<br /> the output:  " + output + "<br />");
}

function FunctionOne(){
...
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
  var user_name = document.getElementById("username").value;
...
}
```

Comment: It all depends on when that code runs. If the code runs before the DOM is built, then there'll be no such element in the DOM.

Comment: **no element that contains an id="password"** - yes,  **or that that specific element's value is null** - no.

Comment: The password code is run, I can see and change the value, then I press a button and the code with the getelementbyid is called. @Pointy

Comment: document.write - not good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your popup.html is not the page that includes login.js - that's why code in login.js does not find a DOM element with id="password". The page that includes login.js contains, however, a button with id="clickMe".

After seeing your `execuateAllCode`:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp - "The write() method is mostly used for testing: If it is used after an HTML document is fully loaded, it will delete all existing HTML." Add a div element where you put any output using innerText or innerHTML instead of using document.write.

Comment: popup.html does contain: <script language="javascript" src="login.js"/>. Is this not what includes login.js? Is there any more info that I should supply in the question?

Comment: should be `<script language="javascript" src="login.js"></script>` - is it loaded?

Comment: I have changed it to your suggestion. login.js is loaded because when the button is pressed that calls login.js the error arises referencing a line in login.js

Comment: time to see the content of login.js or at least the function `execuateAllCode`

Comment: aha! http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp - "The write() method is mostly used for testing: If it is used after an HTML document is fully loaded, it will delete all existing HTML." Add a div element where you put any output using innerText or innerHTML instead of using document.write.

Comment: Thank you so much, that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Your are fetching that element which not loaded yet(DOM is not loaded). That's why you are facing the issue.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  /*Do that stuff in this function*/
};
```

For more reference check this link.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload 
Hope this will help :)

Comment: I added: window.onload = function() {
  execuateAllCode()
};
 and it just added another error and did not solve the original error.

Comment: You should add script tag before end of body tag.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is :

1. Initialize variable **password** outside the function and then declare it
2. Or you can use **window.onload = function_Name;**
3. Why don't you call function on login button click or any event ?

Comment: I do not understand exactly what you mean on any point, but I have added the code into the question

Comment: I added window.onload = execuateAllCode(); and it only deleted some fields and destroyed the styling

Comment: Visit : https://jsfiddle.net/NitinBagoriya/Ldgz1fba/
and let me know if something else you want. :)

Answer (score -1):

A great way to debug javascript is warping your variables and events in a console.log and checking their result in the browser console.

Try adding console.log(password) right after you set it equal to the value of the input. This will tell you if that jQuery functionality is working. That will help you find out what the HTML is "seeing"